# SQL to dBase Query Translator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dbase, xbase

Is anyone aware of an application that will allow me to convert some existing SQL queries into dBase? I have an application that I need to program but it prefers dBase queries to SQL queries. I've written a working SQL query, but now need to figure out what the query would look like in dBase.

Comment: dbase!! that brings back memories :-) :-) Good to see its still around..

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool I was recommended in the past for similar conversions, you'll have to look at the documentation for use of dBase. it's called http://www.toadworld.com.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Probably [DBF Commander Professional](http://elphsoft.com/dbfcommander.html) can help you. It supports SQL querying to dBase and VFP DBF files.